# Using IN statement in CodeIgniter query()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I have this method to retrieve my data:

```
    public function retrieve_not_members($group_id){
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM pnp_officer_tbl WHERE pnp_id NOT IN (SELECT pnp_id FROM group_members_tbl WHERE group_id = ?)";
        $this->db->query($sql, array($group_id));       

        echo $this->db->last_query();

        $query = $this->db->get();
        $data = $this->return_data($query);
        var_dump($data);
        }
```

It returned false. However, when i tried to query the returned string by `$this->db->last_query();` directly in my database it is working properly. Why is that so?

This is the query string returned:

> SELECT * FROM pnp_officer_tbl WHERE pnp_id NOT IN (SELECT pnp_id FROM
>   group_members_tbl WHERE group_id = 'GROUP-0002')

I am looking for answers for almost 1 hour now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `$this->db->get()` is superfluous since you already made an `$this->db->query()`. After the `->query()` method, return the response thru `->result()`:

```
public function retrieve_not_members($group_id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pnp_officer_tbl WHERE pnp_id NOT IN (SELECT pnp_id FROM group_members_tbl WHERE group_id = ?)";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($group_id));       
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: OMG! You just saved my life! Thanks!